# Magento has become incredibly slow, timing out, errors, cpu abuse

Tags: theme, custom, .htaccess

I have been using Magento for around a month and it was never this troubled. I recently reinstalled it and put on a theme i bought, EM Gamewin. In order for this theme to work I needed to use the sample.htaccess file. My htaccess now has some 219 lines in the file. That got the theme going, but along with it caused massive issues.

I often lockup/timeout, and one error came up with a code error to do with zend caching (which i dont have any Mage Caching activated).
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/saltante/public_html/pcstore/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 747

This issue has been causing my CPU (50% of a cpu) to max at 100% and results in my account being limited.

I also have issues of page timeouts when saving, yet the changes ARE saved.

I am wondering if anyone has had similar issues or knows if there are some htaccess lines that could be causing this.

Also Should i be using Magento caching as well as Cloudflare, I could not get fooman speedster working it produced errors so i ignored Mage caching.

Any answers on what may cause this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just convert your site to HHVM with Nginx - it's the little secret service providers don't want retailers to know about. With it you don't need an FPC and it reduces your server specs 5-10fold so you can run high performance sites on ridiculously small hardware. We can run on the smallest cloud instances with the setup - it's obscene. It's a retailer win:win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/saltante/public_html/pcstore/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 747

You should adjust this setting in your php.ini file.  Ideally you will increase the value from 30 seconds.

```
max_execution_time
```

> Also Should i be using Magento caching as well as Cloudflare, I could not get fooman speedster working it produced errors so i ignored Mage caching.

I would definitely suggest using Magento's caching irregardless of if you use a service like Cloudflare or not.  Using them both in conjunction will not cause a conflict.  The [Fooman Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html) module doesn't have anything to do with caching. Instead it combines many of your front-end assets to speed up your page load times for your store's visitors.

Your current hosting solution does not sound like it's sufficient, so I would recommend upgrading your hosting.

Comment: Sorry for raising the dead here, but thanks, this has now been sorted, I now has 100% 2 cpus, 4gb ram and 4mb i/o. All is fine and ive had freelancers helping me with my site so they have done my .htaccess etc and everything appears good.

Comment: Its not the quickest, but should do for the time being and some settings arent ideal like litespeed web server, no pecona mysql and a few others. But im much happier now with the extra resources, I havent had any timeout issues since :)